# What's the difference between using any and nothing when specifying a library in pubspec.yaml file?

Tags: flutter

`pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  foo: any
  bar:
```

When I run `pub get` command, the latest version of both the libraries are included in my `pubspec.lock` file. So, what's the difference between these two ways of specifying a library? And if there is none, then why `any` exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no difference between the two, `any` is more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Dart.dev page about package dependencies](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#traditional-syntax):

> The string any allows any version. This is equivalent to an empty version constraint, but is more explicit. Although any is allowed, we don’t recommend it.

So, using the keyword `any` or an empty string is equivalent. However, `any` is more explicit and **not** recommended to be used, since if the API of the package you are depending on receives breaking changes in the future, your application won't work correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much, I also found the same when I answered it.

Answer (score 1):

> any

will let you update the dependency always to the latest version even if that's mean your project won't be compatible with the library or vice versa.

> empty

will let you update the dependency but it will consider the project compatibility with the library or vice versa.